# NLog: is it possible to change source name from code?

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

Is it possible to change the `source` name thru code? My solution has several modules and I want to separate them when viewing the logs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="EventLog" name="eventlog" layout="${message}" log="Application" source="MyAwesomeSolution"/>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="eventLog" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Also, how do I log objects as xml? e.g. if I do this -  `logger.Info("Results - {0}", person);` I want to view the `person` object as XML in my event log. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initalize your Logger object with

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

then you can add

`${callsite}` to your layout in config file

e.g.

```
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="EventLog" name="eventlog" layout="${callsite}:${message}" log="Application" source="MyAwesomeSolution"/>
</targets>
```

More info @ ${callsite} is [here](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Callsite_layout_renderer).